# Background is not showing up when content is added?

Tags: css

For some reason when I add a width and height to **.left-section**, **.section-page-layout-container** doesn't expand and show the background, but if I add a height to **.section-page-layout-container** the background gradient repeats perfectly and every pixel is filled.

I tried messing around with the code but nothing seemed to work. Must be another stupid mistake.

Hopfully you good folks can help me out :)

Thanks in Advance!

> My HTML

```
    <section class="section-page-layout-container">
        <div class="section-page-layout">
            <div class="left-section">
                <header>

                </header>
            </div>
            <div class="right-module-section">

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

> My CSS

```
.section-page-layout-container {
    background:#984B09;
    background: url('../img/section-page-oj_gradient-background.png') repeat-y;
    background-size:contain;
    width: 100%;
}
.section-page-layout {
    width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
}
.left-section {
    width: 585px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #000000;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Might be a float issue. Try adding "overflow:hidden" to .section-page-layout

Comment: Why can't you have a height on `.section-page-layout-container`?

Comment: Morpheus, because the height is dynamic. My template is WordPress is the height can very.

Comment: Billy Moat, that was exactly it :) Thanks! Also if you write a answer Ill select you as best! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use overflow: hidden

```
.section-page-layout-container {
    background:#984B09;
    background: url('../img/section-page-oj_gradient-background.png') repeat-y;
    background-size:contain;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When you have floated object inside an object the container collaps, thats why u need a clearfix

Comment: Glad i could help, if you want u can choose as correct answer